# How to See if a String Contains Another String in Django Template

Tags: python, django

This is my code in a template.

```
{% if 'index.html' in  "{{ request.build_absolute_uri  }}" %} 
    'hello'
{% else %}      
    'bye'
{% endif %}
```

Now my url value currently is `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login?next=/index.html"`

Even though `"index.html"` is there in the string it still prints bye.

When I run the same code in a python shell it works. Not sure what the mistake is.

Comment: write a custom template tags that will help you

Comment: may be this snippet https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/ may help you

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try removing the extra `{{...}}` tags and the `"..."` quotes around `request.build_absolute_uri`, it worked for me.

Since you are already within an `{% if %}` tag, there is no need to surround `request.build_absolute_uri` with `{{...}}` tags.

```
{% if 'index.html' in request.build_absolute_uri %}
    hello
{% else %}
    bye
{% endif %}
```

Because of the quotes you are literally searching the string `"{{ request.build_absolute_uri  }}"` and not the evaluated Django tag you intended.

Comment: perfect @farmerjoe `{% if 'index.html' in request.build_absolute_uri %}` this does work for me. I am supposed to write custom template tags. But that worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe too late but here is a lightweight version :

```
{{ 'hello 'if 'index.html' in request.build_absolute_uri else 'bye' }}
```

This can be tested with Jinja:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> t = Template("{{ 'hello 'if 'index.html' in request.build_absolute_uri else 'bye' }}")
>>> request = {}
>>> request['build_absolute_uri']='...index.html...'
>>> t.render(request=request)
'hello '
>>> request['build_absolute_uri']='something else...'
>>> t.render(request=request)
'bye'
>>>
```

Comment: I like your technique for testing Jinja2 template directly with Python. I definitely plan on using this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding the negative option of "not contains":

```
{% if 'index.html' not in request.build_absolute_uri %}
    hello
{% else %}
    bye
{% endif %}
```

And:

`{{ 'hello 'if 'index.html' not in request.build_absolute_uri else 'bye' }}`

Answer (score 1):

adding another option that might be useful (that's what I was looking for)

case-insensitive string contains (with **lower** filter)

```
{% if 'index.html' in request.build_absolute_uri|lower %}
    hello
{% else %}
    bye
{% endif %}
```