# How to display user url avatar

Tags: django

i made a function that generates avatars for users when they create a profile:

users/models.py

```
def random_image():
    directory = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media')
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    images = [file for file in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, file))]
    rand = choice(images)
    return rand


class Profile(models.Model):     
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar_new = models.ImageField (default=random_image)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

How can I now display this url img as a picture?

Comment: do you want to display it on template

Comment: The attribute is `url`, so `user.profile.avatar_new.url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the user available as `user` in your template, you can display the image like this:

```
<img src="{{ user.profile.avatar_new.url }}" alt="user avatar" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work! But I have such a problem. I am using the django-avatar library, and there is a setting like this: DEFAULT_URL = (media / default.jpg), I would like to display not a static image, but avatar_new for default users. How can i do this?

Comment: Without knowing the library, you could perhaps check whether the url property is set and the display an avatar depending on that. Something like this perhaps: `<img src="{% if user.profile.avatar_new.url %}{{ user.profile.avatar_new.url }}{% else %}{{ user.profile.avatar_new }}{% endif %}" alt="user avatar" />`

Comment: the problem is that django-avatar assigns media / defalut.jpg to all new users. I would like the users.avatar_new avatars to be displayed by default, but I don't know how to do this (

Comment: Would even I put it this way, I would like to assign an avatar from the avatar_new field to the avatar (user) field. If you have time, I could show the django-avatar add avatar function

Comment: You can also check whether `default.jpg` is in the url and then display something else. Checking for occurances in a string works the same as in Python but here's a link regardless: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19628156/11264793